# Drupal: How do I create a link to open a GMap marker/popup from outside map?

Tags: google-maps, drupal-6, view, location

I am using Views to create 2 things
1: Locations list (table) PAGE
2: GMap ATTACHMENT

What I'd like to do is link the location title in the locations list to marker/popup in the map.

I've found sites that allow me to do this outside of Drupal, but would like to keep the site "Drupal Friendly".

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated!!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion on this page should answer your question.

http://drupal.org/node/791998

Comment: Well I kind of got it to work. It only works for the first two locations.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add this code below in relative tpl file of drupal.

"*seeMap a*" is achor link when we click then google map pop open.

This is code which trigger popup:

```
GEvent.trigger(Drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers[i].marker, "click");
```

"auto1map" depends your setting.

This is the code for to move position top:

```
  var _pos = $('#banner').position(); 
      _pos_top = _pos.top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:eval(_pos_top) - 50},500);
```

**Main code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.seeMap a').each(function(i){

       $(this).bind('click', function(){
           var _pos = $('#banner').position(); 
       _pos_top = _pos.top;

       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:eval(_pos_top) - 50},500);
                    GEvent.trigger(Drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers[i].marker, "click");
                    return false;
                });
            });


        });
```